# accessing class present inside a class

Tags: java, javafx

Please consider the following code:

I have two classes : ClassA and ClassB defined inside ClassA.java and ClassB.java

**Initial Scenario:**

I have something like the following inside the ClassA:

```
public class ClassA extends Task<Integer> {
   @Override
        protected Integer call() throws Exception {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
}
```

And in ClassB.java , I was using Class A, something like the following:

```
public ClassB implements Initializable {

public ClassA[] QR;

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        for(int i=0; i<1; i++) {
            QR[i] = new ClassA(i);
            // My other stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

**Changes that I have made:**

I have decided to use 10 different classes inside ClassA now like the following:

```
public ClassA {

    public class Class1 extends Task<Integer> {
       @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                // My logic here
            }
    }

    public class Class2 extends Task<Integer> {
       @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                // My logic here
            }
    }

    public class Class3 extends Task<Integer> {
       @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                // My logic here
            }
    }

    public class Class4 extends Task<Integer> {
       @Override
            protected Integer call() throws Exception {
                // My logic here
            }
    }

    // and so on until Class10

}// END of ClassA
```

**My Question:**

1) In ClassB.java, how should I access Class1 , Class2 until Class 10 so that I can define something like the following for all the 10 classes :

```
@Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
    {
      for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
            {
                QR[i] = new ClassA(i); 
                // My other stuff here 
             }
    }
```

Because if I plan to do something like the following :

```
`public Class1[] QR1`, then it throws error.
```

Comment: Does "i" correspond to the number in a class name?
(i.e. for i=1 create instance of Class1, for i=2 create instance of Class2, and so on)

Comment: @Constantine Not really. It's just related with the `i` defined in the for loop  above. Do you think that I should do something like that?

Comment: It's up to you. I'm just trying to understand what is that you want to accomplish. If not sure, then most likely you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Constantine Actually, I decided to create a separate class rather than defining all the classes in one class. And it worked. But still for 100 connections, I will  have to define 100 classes which is something odd. Do you think I can get rid of defining 100 classes by any chance?

Comment: Sure, can you update your question with implementation of Class1-ClassN? I'm curious how "// My logic here" looks like in each class.

Comment: @Constantine I created a new thread for the different approach. Please take a look at it here :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22900677/threads-are-not-executing-independently-but-sequentially

Answer (score 0):

I hope this piece of text from oracle docs answers your question:

> An instance of InnerClass can exist only within an instance of
>   OuterClass and has direct access to the methods and fields of its
>   enclosing instance.
>
> To instantiate an inner class, you must first instantiate the outer
>   class. Then, create the inner object within the outer object with this
>   syntax:
>
> OuterClass.InnerClass innerObject = outerObject.new InnerClass();

For example,
QR[i].Class1 test = QR[i].new Class1();

Comment: Thanks.How should I go about defining something like `QR[i] = new ClassA(i);` for Class1 ?

Comment: If I do something like that, then in Netbeans I am getting an error:

Either it's askign me to 

1) Create class "Class1" in package mypackage

2) Create class "Class1" in mypackage.ClassB 

Please advise. It think it's not able to access that class. What could be the reason?

Comment: Instead of QR[i]= new ClassA(i); you have to try QR[i]=new ClassA(); And then access Class1 as QR[i].Class1 test = QR[i].new Class1();