# Error: asking to create a new class while accessing innerclass

Tags: java, inner-classes

I am trying to access innerclass Class1 defined in ClassA from ClassB

**ClassB.java**

```
public class ClassB implements Initializable {
    public ClassA[] QR;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        for(int i=0; i<1; i++)
        {
            //QR[i] = new ClassA(i);
            QR[i].Class1 class1obj = QR[i].new Class1();

            //prog_QR[i].progressProperty().bind(QR[i].progressProperty());
            prog_QR[i].progressProperty().bind(class1obj.progressProperty());
            //lab_QR[i].textProperty().bind(QR[i].messageProperty());
            lab_QR[i].textProperty().bind(class1obj.messageProperty());
            // My other stuff here
        }
    } 
}
```

**ClassA.java**

```
public class ClassA {    
    public class Class1 extends Task<Integer> {
      // Constructor Created
       Class1() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change  body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
       @Override
       protected Integer call() throws Exception {
           // My logic here
       }
    }
}
```

At line `QR[i].Class1 class1obj = QR[i].new Class1();`,I am getting an error in Netbeans and
it's either askign me to

1) Create class "Class1" in package mypackage

2) Create class "Class1" in mypackage

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please make more effort to format your code in future. The code in this post is all over the place. (I've edited it now to be more readable.)

Comment: Sure, sorry about that !

Answer (score 2):

When you declare a variable, the part to the left of the variable name has to be a type name.

```
QR[i].Class1
```

isn't a class name. `QR[i]` is a *value* within an array. There isn't a different class for each value in the array. You want:

```
ClassA.Class1 class1obj = QR[i].new Class1();
```

Personally I'd try to avoid inner classes unless you *really* need them anyway. Does your inner class definitely need to be an inner class rather than just a nested class?

In addition, your class declarations are broken. These:

```
public ClassA {
...
public ClassB {
```

need to be:

```
public class ClassA {
...
public class ClassB {
```

As a complete example, this code compiles fine:

```
public class ClassA {
    public class Class1 {}
}

public class ClassB {    
    public ClassA[] QR = new ClassA[1];

    public void foo() {
        QR[0] = new ClassA();
        ClassA.Class1 class1obj = QR[0].new Class1();
    }
}
```

Comment: No it doesn't need to be inner class. But I have to define 10 Classes inside Class A, so I thought Innerclass option will be good. what would you suggest?

Comment: @John: Declare them as *static* classes - so they're nested, but not inner classes. (Do they really need to be inside ClassA at all?) See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: Just to clear things up for OP: classes inside another class that are not defined as *static* are *inner*, which means they need an instance of enclosing class to be instantiatied. Also consider why you need to put them inside class A, at first glance that makes no sense.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Please refer my previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22818263/accessing-class-present-inside-a-class 
Do you think I need to define 10 different Classes and should not include them inside Class A ?

Comment: @John: Well if you need all the different logic, then you could certainly have 10 classes, but I'd be tempted to make them top level classes. Or *possibly* have methods within `ClassA` which return instances of anonymous classes implementing the task. It's hard to say for sure when everything's so abstract.

Comment: @JonSkeet 1) After using `ClassA.Class1 class1obj = QR[i].new Class1();` , I  getting an error "Cannot Find Class1" error. 2) I need to follow some steps of binding to progressbar (I updated my original post) just to make things more clear what I am trying to do.

Comment: @John: Well are the classes in different packages? I've got a short but complete version working - I'll edit it into my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet No. They are in the same package.

Comment: @John: Well then it's unclear what you're doing wrong - see my edit. My guess is that your class names aren't *really* `ClassA` and `ClassB` etc, and that in your *real* code you've got a typo in the name. But we can't really tell - all I can tell is that the code I've posted *will* compile.

Comment: @JonSkeet  1)The error disappeared when I created a constructor in Class A, as shown. But it's an empty constructor as shown in the code I edited. Do you know why it is mandatory to have that?

2) Also I have changed the variables `QR[i].progressProperty()` to ` class1obj.progressProperty()` as there was error in this line as well. Am I doing right here?

Comment: @John: You shouldn't need an explicit constructor there unless it's something to do with `Task<Integer>`, but we'd really need to see the full code to know more. Likewise I can't tell anything about `progressProperty()` based on this code, but it's really nothing to do with the topic of this question. Please stick to one question per post - Stack Overflow isn't really designed for "question creep" like this.